# Car and Med Insurance?

Tags: united-states, medical, insurance, probate, automotive

If somebody were to get into a bad car accident, the med costs can rack up, and it'd be best to have insurance burgeon a portion of the debt.  But let's say that due to financial straits, said person figured suicide in such a scenario so as to escape debt and the bill.  But what happens if he/she survived and unconsciously underwent ER?  Then if he/she suicided, there would normally be the debt from the operation.  If he/she suicided, then perhaps friends or family would have to inherit the debt? - in which case, all of this seems like an awkward debt generation hole in the economy.  Is there law or insurance policy compensating for this?

Comment: In what state or country?

Comment: What makes you think friends and/or family become responsible for a person's debts upon death?

Comment: I guess any state in the U.S..  (I'm also guessing this happened somewhere in Law & Order tv?``)

Comment: Maybe obligations or something.  I was just wondering where an ER debt would go in this case.

Comment: Any debt would pass to the decedent's estate.

Comment: Oh.  Right, that would be reasonable.  The details of which depend on the state and other stuff...  Hahaah...  Well done.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Any debts that a person has are to be paid by their estate. Whoever administers the estate must, in all states, publish an announcement to the effect that Smith is deceased and all claims must be made by such and such date, probably within 90 days. If (this is a small if) the hospital takes 6 months to make their claim, it is too late for them (provided that notice was properly given).

There are also limits on how much can be collected, the simplest case being that you can't collect more than what is in the estate. There can also be complexities regarding order of priority – as you would expect, you must pay debts to the government first. That could include the Medicaid clawback (officially "estate recovery"), however, in the circumstance that you describe it doesn't sound like that would be applicable.
There may also be exemptions in a state, for example in Florida, your registered homestead (property of a certain size that you have been living in and have filed the paperwork for) cannot be seized to pay debts, even after death.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was hoping for a best answer to the thread.

Comment: Usually, expenses of a last illness and funeral expenses are higher in priority than taxes or Medicaid clawback. As a matter of U.S. constitutional law, mere publication isn't sufficient to bar a known creditor who lacks actual knowledge of the publication, who must receive a letter in the mail instead to be barred, unless there is a post-death statute of limitations (often called a non-claim statute) that is not conditional upon publication or receipt of notice. Otherwise, spot on. The estate has liability only to the extent of its non-exempt assets. The next of kin doesn't inherit the debt.

Comment: One other fine point. If the debt is covered by insurance, the insurance company (usually) still has to pay the debt, even if the claim is otherwise barred as to the non-exempt assets of the estate.